# What to do when a dog has a cold?

Tags: dogs

It seems our 12 week old puppy has gotten a cold from us.

Our oldest son came home buggered and passed it on to me and put me home for the day. Doggy is here with us and I just noticed her sneezing and with the nose dripping.

Is there anything to do when dogs get a cold?

Is there any medication we should give her (I'm more thinking maybe fruits or something)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend a nice trip to the vet. You never know. Only the vet can conclude what is really going on with your dog. I can't conclude on any medication and such because 1. I am not a vet. And 2. I can't see your dog in person and don't know for sure what is going on. So take your dog to the vet, and the vet will tell you for sure what the best thing(s) to do is/are.

Comment: "Take it do the vet." The best thing to do. :)

Answer (score 2):

Rhinoviruses, which are the most common cause of colds in humans, are not transmissible to dogs.  In fact, it's pretty safe to say that there are virtually no "cold"-type viruses that can pass from people to dogs (or vice versa), so the puppy did not get this from your son.  Just as in people, there are no common/safe medications that will speed resolution of upper respiratory viral infections.  There is the possibility that this is something like Bordetella/infectious tracheobronchitis complex, so it is definitely worth a trip to the vet. NEVER give a medication to a pet without consulting a vet--many human medications are toxic to cats and dogs, and even the "safe" medications may be dosed very differently in a pet compared to a human.  Even fruits can be problematic--grapes and raisins can be toxic to dogs.  Finally, make sure the puppy is well vaccinated: distemper, a really nasty and frequently fatal disease, can initially look like a cold, but is a really preventable disease with appropriate vaccination.

Comment: Ah cool. Thanks for the clarification. During my day home, I saw her sneezing and a dripping nose in another couple of occasions. However, she was behaving fine for the whole day, running jumping and all sorts... Also, I worded wrongly (and thought about it before posting) about "medication". I usually share apples and pears with her and was thinking there were other fruits and something that would boost her immunologic system.